# solving orientation issue in android

Tags: android

I have designed 2 xml files, one portrait and another for landscape for a single activity. I have called one xml file using `setContentView(R.layout.portrait);` in my `onCreate`class. How should I call xml file for landscape.

Comment: You should accept my answer by pressing the V button next to it

Answer (score 1):

You should have the same file name for both layout resource files. The only difference is that the landscape layout folder will be called "layout-land" and inside you'll have the layout xml file in landscape mode. When the app is running, Android knows to take the correct xml file and set the layout according to the current mode so you don't have to worry yourself about selecting the proper xml layout file.

Comment: Ya. I did the same way you described. I have 2 xml files of same activity, one in "layout" folder  and another in "layout-land" folder. Even then when I change the orientation the screen is not changing to landscape. I used `Toast` in `onConfigurationChanged` method and that works properly when I change orientation.

Comment: check if your manifest might got an orientation settings on your activity or you may got a setOrientation method invoked somewhere in your code